# ¿Cómo indicarle a Laravel/Eloquent que mi tabla tiene una clave primaria formada por N columnas?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Por lo que estuve leyendo Eloquent no tiene o no tenía compatibilidad con esto. (Indicar que una primary key está formada por 2 o más columnas).

[Este post](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355) es muy interesante, dónde algunos usuarios solicitan la integración de esta funcionalidad, otros dan "soluciones" temporales, y otros opinas que Laravel no tendría que soportar esto. (OJO: data del 2014-2015).

También he leído [este otro](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5517) y finalmente en uno dónde se puede resumir una solución (basado en los anteriores) [es este post de stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332005/laravel-model-with-two-primary-keys-update).

Al intentar usar este código (el del último link), recibo el siguiente error:

```
Declaration of App\Models\Dato::setKeysForSaveQuery(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) must be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setKeysForSaveQuery($query)
```

En /App/Models/MyModels tengo esto:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Dato extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'datos';
    protected $primaryKey = ['tipo_id', 'servicio_id', 'columna_id', 'dia', 'hora'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = ['valor', 'servicio_id', 'columna_id', 'tipo_id', 'dia', 'hora'];

    public function columna()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Columna::class);
    }
    public function servicio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Servicio::class);
    }

        /**
     * Set the keys for a save update query.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
    {
        $keys = $this->getKeyName();
        if(!is_array($keys)){
            return parent::setKeysForSaveQuery($query);
        }

        foreach($keys as $keyName){
            $query->where($keyName, '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName));
        }

        return $query;
    }

    /**
     * Get the primary key value for a save query.
     *
     * @param mixed $keyName
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName = null)
    {
        if(is_null($keyName)){
            $keyName = $this->getKeyName();
        }

        if (isset($this->original[$keyName])) {
            return $this->original[$keyName];
        }

        return $this->getAttribute($keyName);
    }
}
```

Interpreto que esas dos funciones que aparecen en el tercer link no van dentro de mi modelo, pero tampoco entiendo dónde van. ¿Me ayudan?

Comment: Creo que sí pueden ir en el modelo. El OP de la respuesta sugiere al final *Sugiero poner esos métodos en un HasCompositePrimaryKey Trait para que pueda usarlo en cualquiera de sus modelos que lo necesite.* Tendrías que mirar cómo es la función en `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setKeysForSaveQuery` para ver por qué no es compatible. A la versión actual, tal vez reciba distinto argumento, o retorne otra cosa.

Comment: Lo de poner el código en: HasCompositePrimaryKey no sé cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Copia la declaración de la función Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setKeysForSaveQuery en tu modelo. Fíjate que no define el tipo de parámetro setKeysForSaveQuery($query) y vos le estás poniendo que sea Builder `setKeysForSaveQuery(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query)`